# How to render realistic ice?

Tags: graphics, unity, shaders, rendering, glsl

I am trying to write an ice shader in Unity that looks good and at least semi-realistic.

If the following shot ([found on Google](http://www.google.com.mx/imgres?start=135&num=10&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=705&tbs=ic:specific,isc:teal&tbm=isch&tbnid=o24OoxLEAuG86M:&imgrefurl=http://blog.kermitweeks.com/?p=358&docid=ALDp03TMFxGLvM&imgurl=http://blog.kermitweeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/blog-shot-3-heli-ice-cave-1024x720.jpg&w=1024&h=720&ei=kvtwT6HsFumvsgKP-8zIDg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=197&vpy=307&dur=633&hovh=188&hovw=268&tx=149&ty=73&sig=107815244113454837401&page=8&tbnh=166&tbnw=221&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:10,s:135)) was CG, what would its shader include? (the foreground cave). I might be wrong but it looks like it even has a different lighting model than the default diffuse.

[image]

Comment: [Here](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut32.html)'s a tutorial for DirectX 11 using HLSL and C++. Maybe you can glean the principles. Also, where did you see that the image was CG? It's reported as real.

Comment: I didn't say it was. I said "if" it was. and Thanks! I'll check it out

Comment: That phenomenon is called subsurface scattering.  It's caused because light penetrates the surface of the material and is scattered through the medium of the material itself.  It's why, for example, human ears look red when backlit.  [Here is a blog post](http://littlecolourbakery.com/pages/research.html) explaining someone's attempt to recreate an ice effect with it.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed the "if".

Comment: @Byte56, No problem

Comment: I suggested opening a Stack Exchange site dedicated to Computer Graphics, and selected this question as an [example question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62667/computer-graphics/62671#62671). Follow [computergraphics.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62667/computer-graphics) if you're interested in seeing the site being launched!

Comment: @wil Nice! But I already started one like that: [Graphics Layer Architecture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61961/graphics-layer-architecture)

Comment: @DantheMan Sorry, I did not notice that the focus of [Graphics Layer Architecture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61961/graphics-layer-architecture) was the same as [Computer Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62667/computer-graphics). Judging by the title only I imagined it was more about low level gpu architectures and graphics libraries architecture. I should probably  delete "Computer Graphics" to avoid the duplicate. Would you consider renaming "Graphics Layer Architecture" so that it sounds like it has a broader focus?

Comment: @wil Ah ok. No problem. Leave you input on the site name [here](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/12627/what-should-the-site-name-and-url-be)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Ice is translucent so I believe the single most important thing you have to simulate in your shader to get realistic results would be **[subsurface scattering](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch16.html)** or SSS for short. SSS basically describes how rays of light penetrate the surface of translucent objects and scatter underneath it, being reflected multiple times in an irregular fashion, before finally exiting through a different location.

Here's a picture that I think demonstrates the effect nicely:

[image]

From the picture in your question we can also see that ice is quite reflective, so you'll probably also want to combine it with some sort of **[environment mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_mapping)** for reflections, and also tone up the **[specularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_highlight)** in order to reinforce the highlights.

You can also try other things such as adding a bit of **[refraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction)**, overlaying some sort of **[noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise)** texture to add a bit of variation, or even some sort of **[bump mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_mapping)** or **[displacement mapping](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter08.html)** for very small and subtle details.

**Resources**

Some other resources that I found while writing the answer:

- http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch16.html
- http://graphics.ucsd.edu/~henrik/papers/fast_bssrdf/
- http://www.jamiemccarter.com/Subsurface_Scattering_%26_Reflections_without_Rays.html
- http://www.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-244/subsurface-scattering/
- http://littlecolourbakery.com/pages/research.html

Comment: You might also want to look into Ambient Occlusion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion) to simulate the darkening in the crags for that is usually pretty hard to get right using just shadows.

Answer (score 14):

One of my students did this a few years ago (using renderman ) but lots of background in the thesis http://nccastaff.bournemouth.ac.uk/jmacey/MastersProjects/MSc09/Salas/index.html